# Jenkins declarative pipeline string parameter with recommendations

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to have a text box that can recommend you entries based on what you are typing?

Something that works like: https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/. Sadly this parameter isn't compatible with pipeline and I cannot use it.

Pipeline generator syntax
[image: Missing from pipeline syntax generator]

Freestyle Job:
[image: How it looks in the freestlye job]

Does an alternative exists?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not supported?? Gosh thats one of the most useful plugins! I can give you a crude solution wherein you could put a `freestyle` job in front of the pipeline job and trigger that and pass your value as a parameter to the `pipeline` job.

Comment: I would say I'm pretty sure. The documentation is 3-4 year old, it doesn't state anything about pipeline and if you go to: yourJenkinsUrl/directive-generator/ and try to generate parameters, you can't see it listed there. Your workaround is tidious and may need maintenance so I would prefer another solution.

Comment: Actually I just tested it with a `Global Choice Parameter` and it worked perfectly fine like this `echo myextensible` . Can you try and share some screenshots.

Comment: Sure, I updated the post.

Comment: Reiterating, I have tested `extensible choice parameter` and it is working with `pipeline` job, your statement "Sadly this parameter isn't compatible with pipeline and I cannot use it." is not right.

Comment: Well then add your solution as answer and I will remove that part. For me it is not working, so from my perspective the statement is right.